# Undefined offset al abrir archivo CSV en PHP

Tags: php, csv

Tengo una lista de productos en un archivo CSV que intento pasar a una base de datos.

Este es mi código para abrir el archivo.

```
$tmp_archivo = "file/catalogo.csv";
$archivo = fopen($tmp_archivo, "r");
$row = 0;
if($archivo){
    while ($datos = fgetcsv($archivo, ",")){
        echo utf8_encode($datos[0])."-".utf8_encode($datos[1])."-".utf8_encode($datos[2])."-".utf8_encode($datos[3])."-".utf8_encode($datos[4])."-".utf8_encode($datos[5])."-".utf8_encode($datos[6])."-".utf8_encode($datos[7])."-"."<br>";
}
}
```

Pero obtengo las siguientes lineas.

```
100010008-Alambre galvanizado Nº 18-KG--10001-HAWA-Z205-;;;-
100010009-Alambre negro recocido Nº 16-KG-COD.ANT.-10001-HAWA-Z205-GRUPO ART. EXT.;;;-

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/Sis_Pecosa/index.php on line 11
100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,;;;--------
```

lineas de mi archivo CSV:

```
100010008,Alambre galvanizado Nº 18,KG,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
100010009,Alambre negro recocido Nº 16,KG,COD.ANT.,10001,HAWA,Z205,GRUPO ART. EXT.
100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
```

Algunas lineas si las imprime normal, otras no, ¿alguna ayuda?

Gracias.

Comment: te recomiendo usar la funcion fputcsv

Comment: Puedes mostrar el contenido de las líneas? Tiene pinta que las líneas que no salen no tienen el separado ',' es por ello que te sale offset. Mira el fichero o realiza una comprobación antes.

Comment: Agregue las lineas como se ven en el archivo.

Comment: Observa que es la 3era línea la que falla y es por las comillas dobles, por lo que toda la línea te lo mete en la posición 0 del array y por eso te da ese error. Revisa como escapar las comillas dobles para la función fgetcsv

Answer (score 0):

No encuentra registros y no llena el array, por ende no genera elemento y no tiene los indices que luego vas a buscar.
Inicializa la variable como array, luego cuenta sus elementos y si este es mayor al indice que necesitas entonces luego puedes intentar acceder a tu indice del array, del contrario, estarás intentando acceder a un indice en un array que no existe y te generará el error.

Comment: el registro existe... modifique mi pregunta y agregue los registros que están en mi archivo...

Answer (score 0):

Te dejare un pequeño ejemplo:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$fp = fopen('mi_archivo.csv', 'w');

foreach ($row as $val) {
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);
```

la posible salida de esto seria algo asi:

```
row1 val1, row1 val2
row2 val1, row2 val2
```

[Documentacion fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php)

Te recomiendo leer la documentacion

Comment: quiero pasar de CSV a base de datos... creo que esto es al revés

Answer (score 0):

espero te ayude:

El problema que tienes es en el csv, estas usando comillas, elimina esas comillas:

100010008,Alambre galvanizado Nº 18,KG,,10001,HAWA,Z205,
100010009,Alambre negro recocido Nº 16,KG,COD.ANT.,10001,HAWA,Z205,GRUPO ART. EXT.

**Error Aquí** -> 100010010,"Alcayata de acero De 2 1/2""",UN,,10001,HAWA,Z205,

abre el archivo en un excel, lo das guardar como : CSV (separado por comas)